# Running orchard CMS version (1.10) and (1.10.1) from visual studio 2015

Tags: orchardcms, visual-studio-2015, orchardcms-1.10

Below is the error that I is displayed when in tried to run Orchard (1.10 and 1.10.1) source from Visual studio 2015 community version.

[image]

I know that it is somehow related with configuration settings, but I am unable to solve it. 
The same files, when placed in the local IIS runs without any problems. Is there anything that I am missing in visual studio 2015?
How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the displayed 'Config file' path corresponding to your folder?
Because it doesn't seem to be a folder coming from the source code.

Sometime, IIS Express messes up when you try to launch a site with the same port that a previously used one.

Try to read your applicationhost.config (see IIS Express in tasks bar to get the path).
You could also try to change the port in Orchard.Web properties.

Comment: @Antonie, I changed the port number in Orchard.Web project properties from 30321 to 30300 and It ran successfully. Thanks for you help.